# Create chapter titles within a view

Tags: 7, views

Hoping for some ideas on how I can create chapter titles to a group of videos that I have on my Drupal 7 site.

Currently each video series is shows with a custom view and grouped with a taxonomy term. I have each video weighted to then display them in the order that I want. Everything works fine. I just need to break them up and create "chapters" to better organize them.

An example of a page on my site can be seen [here](http://www.myonlinetechguy.com/videos/introduction-mavericks).

And example of what I am looking for:

```
Heading
-Video 1
-Video 2
-Video 3
Heading
-Video 4
Heading
-Video 5 
-Video 6
```

Comment: For anyone interested I rephrased the question and asked it [here][1]. 


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98960/how-to-dynamically-group-content-in-a-views-listing

Answer (score 0):

What I would is to use another field (assuming that the chapter names are unique) to identify which chapter it is a part of and do a secondary grouping with the field in views.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Antonio. But what if the number of chapters differs for each set of videos that I put up? Sometimes I would have 3 chapters and others I would have 5. That would mean that the number of fields would have to change constantly.